# How can I access the value of a variable and append it with my function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I realize this may be a basic question but I'm stomped. I have a variable that is doing some math to randomly pick a number from 1 - 6. I want take the value of that variable and append it to the DOM but it's returning 'undefined' when I log it to the console. How can I access the value of the number that is currently saved to the variable 'randomNumber' and append it to the DOM? Ideally, I want to create a function that every time it's call will generate random number and append it to #instructions. I assume I have to do this by putting randomNumber inside of the function dice1() but whether I make it global or put it inside the function it returns undefined.

```
   function dice1(){
       var randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
       $('#instructions').append(randomNumber);
   }

    dice1();

    console.log(dice1());
```

Comment: `s/stomped/stumped/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just return the value

```
function dice1(){
   var randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   $('#instructions').append(randomNumber);
   return randomNumber;
```

}

Comment: I already tried that before I posted this question. When I call the function It's not appending. I also checked that the id in the function is correct ... The problem was I'm missing $(function(){

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `randomNumber` in the `dice1()` function.

Try this:

```
function dice1() {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    $('#instructions').append(randomNumber);
    return randomNumber;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/808oyLdL/1)**

Comment: Why use the append() outside the function?

Answer (score 0):

The function has no return statement, so it returns *undefined*. If you want to to return *randomNumber*, then do that:

```
return randomNumber;
```

Also, [*.append()*](https://api.jquery.com/append/) is not the method you're after, try [*.text()*](https://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('#instructions').text(randomNumber);
```

#### Edit

It seems that the real problem was calling *dice1* before the element existed. In that case, plain javascript would have thrown an error when an attempt was made to write to the element's content. jQuery hides such errors.

Even if the function is called after the element exists, it will continue to return *undefined* until a return statement is added that returns some other value.

Comment: Why use text() instead of append()?

Comment: There are links to related documentation in the answer. *append* is intended for inserting elements, *text* is for inserting text. You are inserting text (by providing a number, but it's converted to a string in the process). So *text* is the more appropriate method, don't make jQuery any slower than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure including jquery.js file since .append() is one of jquery method. try something like this,

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

demo in [**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/378sf0y3/)

If you want to print out the random number, you have to return randomNumber in dice1().

JS

```
   function dice1(){
       var randomNumber =  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
       $('#instructions').append(randomNumber);
       return randomNumber;
   }
   dice1();
   console.log(dice1());
   alert(dice1());
```

HTML

```
<div id='instructions'>hello</div>
```